# Django Model use of keyword IN

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to figure out how to use the IN keyword in a django model query.

I was attempting to replace:

```
db = database.connect()
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT MAX(Date) FROM `Requests` WHERE UserId = %%s AND VIN = %%s AND Success = 1 AND RptType in %s" % str(cls.SuperReportTypes), (userID, vin))
```

With this:

```
myrequests = Request.objects.filter(user=userID, vin = vin, report_type in cls.SuperReportTypes)
myrequests.aggregate(Max('Date'))
```

I get a:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg (<console>, line 1)
```

When I remove the ending `"report_type in cls.SuperReportTypes"` the query functions properly.

I recognize that there is a way to do this after the query managing the result set but I was hoping to deal with this in such a way that MYSQL would do the execution.

Answer (score 2):

[`field__in=seq`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong in statement

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in